# qmethod r package dataframe disconnect

Tags: r

Positive my data is in the right format to be read into qmethod() (see [cookbook](http://aiorazabala.github.io/qmethod/Cookbook)), but

```
{r analysis}
# Run the analysis
# Create an object called 'results', and put the output
# of the function 'qmethod' into this object
# (replace the number of factor 'nfactors' as necessary)
results <- qmethod(Q_R_input, nfactors = 3)
```

returns

> Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist. x Locations 18, 44, 13, 45, 51, etc. don't exist. ℹ There are only 1 column.

Sure this is something quick, thank you!

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).